# Pycharm type hinting of instance variable

Tags: python, pycharm, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, type-hinting

Is there some way to specific type of instance variable, consistent with the sphinx specification?

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass


class Bar:
    def foo(self):
        pass


class ExampleError(Exception):
    """
    :ivar Foo msg: descr
    :ivar Bar code: descr
    """

    def __init__(self, param, param2):
        """
        :param Foo param: descr
        :param Bar param2: descr
        """
        self.msg = None
        self.code = None
```

This case generates the documentation properly. ( class ExampleError with variables msg, code and their types)

But pycharm type hinting on *self.msg* doesn't work.

If i use:

```
self.msg = param
```

Type hinting on *self.msg* use *:param Foo param: descr*

This is work for *msg*, but its hack for pycharm:

```
class ExampleError(Exception):
    """
    :var Foo msg: descr
    :type msg: Foo
    :var Bar code: descr
    """
```

Comment: Have you considered using native type hinting? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/